# Non numerical indexing in multidimensional matrices (lists)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matrix, scipy

Is there any way to create a 2D matrix with NON numerical indexing? and MORE importantly GET/SET the values by using those non numerical indexes?

I mean having a 2D matrix like

```
   mat=
         one  two  three
     A    1    2      3
     B    4    5      6
```

and then be able to SET/GET like

```
    >>>m13=mat[A,three]
    >>> m13
    >>> 3
```

any idea snippet appreciated. I was thinking of using 'Pandas' but couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
import pandas as pd

mat = pd.DataFrame({'three': {'A': 3, 'B': 6},
                    'two': {'A': 2, 'B': 5}, 
                    'one': {'A': 1, 'B': 4}}, 
                    columns = ['one','two','three'])

print mat
   one  two  three
A    1    2      3
B    4    5      6

#GET
print mat.loc['A', 'three']
3

#SET
mat.loc['A', 'three'] = 10
print mat
   one  two  three
A    1    2     10
B    4    5      6
```

EDIT:

You can create [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) from `numpy array` too:

```
print arr
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]

mat = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=['A','B'], columns=['one','two','three'])
   one  two  three
A    1    2      3
B    4    5      6
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, Could you show how did you create 'mat' ?

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! And thank you for accepting.